# How Laravel manage the scheduler?

Tags: php, laravel

The question may already asked before at [How Laravel knows when the scheduler has been updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093287/how-laravel-knows-when-the-scheduler-has-been-updated) but seem it couldn't find the final answer.

Laravel's scheduler system works is it uses a cron job that runs once every minute. **How Laravel know the latest time ran? Where Laravel store the schedule information for the latest run?**

I think it's stored somewhere in database or file or cache but it's seem not true.

Comment: My opinion its not storing. If cron job run a function in every minute, its just check is there anything? If a value is exist, run the function. Seems didn't need store anything.

Comment: if we schedule a task for running every 5 minutes, so every minute cronjob run why it know the task was run before to skip?

Answer (score 1):

The CRON job runs the scheduler. Laravel doesn't know anything about when it last ran. (Though it can know when it is still running: [`withoutOverlapping()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps))

Compare it with with you manually executing a script. You take a look at your watch and every minute, you run a script. You are the CRON job and the script is Laravel. The script doesn't have to know when it last ran, that's what you are there for.

Comment: Thank @Loek , but I consider if we put a task run frequency every 5 minutes, so the cron job run schedule every minute, I think it must know the latest time was run this task for tracking the task already run or not

Comment: `if currentServerTimeInMinutes % 5 != 0 then doNothing()`?

Comment: It seem not true, the scheduler log write it ran at 2018-06-06 07:50:09 for a task run frequenct every 5 minutes. I reseach in Laravel core and they store file in "storage/framework/schedule-*" file to record task run (function mutexName() in Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event) but I couldn't find any files were written at there "storage/framework/schedule-..."

Comment: Ah okay, then I wouldnt really know. If I can find some time later today, I'll try to look it up.

Comment: Thank @Loek so much!

Comment: After hours research, I realize your answer is correct and Laravel don't need to store last run, it's so magic!